# How to plot a scatter diagram using rpy2 in python?

Tags: python-2.7, rpy2

I have a dataset like below in dictionary format,

```
data={'a': [10, 11,12,5,4,3,1], 'b': [7, 18,5,11,9,2,0]}
```

How we can make a scatter plot in python using rpy2? where x axis is the months and y axis are the mutiples of 5? we need to plot the graph with the above values where a and b are the data points

```
Months should be based on the length of each key i.e for the above data we have 7 months since we have 7 data points
```

Comment: @Noah How to draw a line graph for the above data points

Comment: Something like this? http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/r/

Comment: I'm not sure what `a` and `b` are in your edited question -- x-axis and y-axis values?

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty involved data structure, and it's not completely clear what you're looking to do in terms of plotting. Here are a few hints, but it'd be easiest to help you if you would post the code you've tried but hasn't worked.

The R `plot` function takes two vectors corresponding to the x-axis values (months, here), and y-axis values (frequencies?). You'll want to go through your `graph_data` dictionary and calculate the y-axis values you want to plot for each month, and then make a corresponding vector for x containing the month numbers. For example:

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [0.7, 0.9, 0.2, 0.4]
```

To do the plotting from rpy2, you'll need to convert the lists to vectors like so:

```
from rpy2 import robjects
x_vector = robjects.IntVector(x)
y_vector = robjects.FloatVector(y)
```

Then do the plotting:

```
robjects.r.plot(x_vector, y_vector, xlab="month", ylab="freq", main="")
```